# localised ip assist + DDOS prevention + google billing

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, cloud, billing, ddos

We are very new in Google Cloud and learning.

I have two question marks in my mind.

First is
Can I create localisation IP addresses for virtual instances? like I open web site with German IP range or another web site I want assign under Italian IP range.
Where is the best place to start or is it possible under cloud.

Second is
We had DDOS attack to under cloud and resources made peak while under attack, Will google charge extreme price for that peak time or will be normal billing.

Second question brings to third one,
We using cloudflare for domains, Is there stable way yo prevent DDOS attacks under google cloud?

I appreciate your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

To your **first point**, are you after finding the shortest path between your users and wherever you serve your content? If that's the case, you can simply put a load balancer in front of your backend services within Google Cloud, with a global public forwarding IP address, and the service itself will take care of redirecting the traffic to the nearest group of machines available. Here is an example of [a HTTP(S) Load Balancer setup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).

Or is localization what you are trying to achieve? In that case I'd rely on more standard forms of handling the language of choice like using browser settings (or user account settings if existing) or the `Accept-Language` header. This is a [valuable resource from LocalizeJS](https://help.localizejs.com/docs/detecting-language-of-a-visitor).

Lastly if you are determined to having multiple versions of your application deployed for the different languages that you support, you could still have an intermediate service that determines the source of the request using IP-based lookups and redirect the user to the version of your choice. Said so, my feeling is that this is a more traditional behavior that in the world of client applications that are responsive and localized on the spot, the extra hop/redirect could get to annoy some users.

To your **second point**, there is a number of protections that are already built-in on some services within Google Cloud, in order to help you protect your applications and machines in different ways. On the DDoS front, you can benefit from policies and protections on the CDN side, where you get cache and scaling based preventive measures.

In addition to that, and if you have a load balancer put in front of your content, you can benefit from protections on layers 3, 4 and 7 of the OSI model. That includes typical HTTP, SYN floods, port exhaustion or NTP amplification attacks.

What this means is that in many of these situations, your infrastructure will not even notice many of these potential attacks, as they'll be alleviated before they reach your infrastructure (and therefore you will not be billed for that). Said so, I have heard and experienced situations in which these protections did not act in a timely fashion, or were triggered at all. In these scenarios, there is a possibility for your system to need to handle that extra load. However, and especially in events when the attack was obviously malicious and documented to be supposedly handled by Google Cloud, there is a chance to make a point with Google in order to get some support on the topic.

A bit more on that [here](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf).

Hope this is helpful.